# Using a single header to simplify many repetitive sources

Tags: c++, header-files

Suppose I have the following interface declaration (assume it has a corresponding well-formed definition in `interface.cpp`):

**interface.hpp**

```
#ifndef INTERFACE_HPP
#define INTERFACE_HPP

#include <iostream>

class Interface {
public:
    Interface();
    virtual void f();
};

#endif
```

I will need to implement this interface many times. Now suppose I have the following implementations, `A` and `B`:

**A.cpp**

```
#include "interface.hpp"

class A : public Interface {
public:
    A() : Interface() {}
    void f() { std::cout << "A"; }
};
```

**B.cpp**

```
#include "interface.hpp"

class B : public Interface {
public:
    B() : Interface() {}
    void f() { std::cout << "B"; }
};
```

There will be many similar implementations, each with their own distinct members and definitions.

Rather than write a corresponding `.hpp` file for every single implementation, include every single one in the `main.cpp` file, and pass every single source to the compilation, I note that it is possible to simply include all of the sources in a single header, such that all definitions will be emplaced into the `main.cpp` file:

**implementations.hpp**

```
#ifndef IMPLEMENTATIONS_HPP
#define IMPLEMENTATIONS_HPP

#include "A.cpp"
#include "B.cpp"

#endif
```

The `#pragma once` directive would be added to `interface.hpp` to avoid multiple inclusion.

Then, `main.cpp` can simply be written as:

**main.cpp**

```
#include "implementations.hpp"

//...
```

Compilation would also only appear as:

`g++ -o out main.cpp interface.cpp`

Would this type of inclusion hierarchy be a valid practice? If not, why should it be avoided?

Comment: Never `#include` any compilation units!

Comment: If you're going to be including a file then stick to the normal conventions and don't call it a cpp file

Comment: if you change just one of `A.cpp` or `B.cpp`, everything else needs to be compiled again,

Comment: Including cpp units is a valid practice for doing unity builds which is a hack per se. So if you consider doing some hack which you fully understand and would like to go ahead with, then why not. Otherwise—don't.